# Angle between 2 vectors

Tags: vectors

Suppose ***v*** and ***w*** are nonzero vectors. Find the angle between v and w if
**||*v*+*w*||=||*v*||=||*w*||**.

I know i have to use the cosine formula to solve this but i'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Drawing a figure, you should see two equilateral triangles appear, hence $120°$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me denote by $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}$ the scalar product of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$. Then
$$
\|\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}\|^2=\|\mathbf{v}\|^2+2\,\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}+\|\mathbf{w}\|^2=\|\mathbf{v}\|^2=\|\mathbf{w}\|^2.
$$
Then
$$
\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}=-\frac{\|\mathbf{v}\|^2}{2}=-\frac{\|\mathbf{w}\|^2}{2}.
$$
You can go on from here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{v}\centerdot\vec{w}}{||\vec{v}||\centerdot||\vec{w}||}$$
Since 
$$||\vec v||=||\vec w||$$
which yields that
$$||\vec{v}||\centerdot||\vec{w}||=\vec v ^2$$
and 
$$||\vec v+ \vec w||=||\vec v||$$
which yields that
$$\vec v^2+ \vec w^2 +2 \vec v \centerdot \vec w=2\vec v^2 +2\vec v \centerdot\vec w=\vec v^2$$
we now obtain
$$\cos \theta = -\frac{\vec v^2}{2\vec v^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Or
$$\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

By the geometric interpretation of a vector sum,

[image: vector triangle]

*But if all sides have the same length...*

I'll let you finish.

Note for this method you do not need to use the cosine formula.